# Consistently inconsistent MySQL query results - 0 vs n rows returned

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables, leagues and teams, and am trying to get the list of team IDs where the league is in a certain state.

```
SELECT t.TeamID 
FROM teams t 
INNER JOIN leagues l ON t.LeagueID = l.LeagueID 
WHERE t.Computer = 1 AND l.BiddingOpen = 1 AND t.Deleted = 0;
```

The code retrieving this is:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(DAL.GetConnectionString()))
{
    if (DAL.OpenConnection(connection))
    {
        MySqlDataReader rsData = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection).ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (rsData.HasRows)
        {
            while (rsData.Read())
            {
                result.Add(rsData.GetInt32(rsData.GetOrdinal("TeamID")));
            }
        }
        rsData.Close();
    }
}
```

When I run the SQL statement in *phpMyAdmin*, I get the expected result of **22** rows. When I run the code in the *debugger*, with or without a breakpoint, in **DEBUG** and **RELEASE** configuration, I get the expected result of **22**. When I run the executable on **another machine**, my logs show I'm getting **0** rows returned.

Thus far I have tried CHECK TABLE on both tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE on both tables, and I upgraded my MySQL.Data.dll to version 8.0.13.0 (from 6.0.5.0). Does anything stand out as to why I would get 0 rows from the .EXE but the correct number of rows the other ways?

Comment: How you make connection string. Check connection string on both machine and verify that it is pointing to same server

Comment: Did you try running it in a _debugger_ on the _"[other] machine"_?  I can see quite a few use cases there where your code has the potential to skip code

Comment: Are you catching errors? Your user may e.g. not have permission to access the server or these specific tables from a remote machine, and, depending how and what you log, an access error may have the same effect on your log as retrieving 0 rows (e.g.: not logging any retrieved rows). Another idea would be that you access a different server than you think (e.g. you may have a server running on both machines with different data, and a hardcoded connection to "localhost" in this particular query)

Comment: My school report card once read 'consistently inconsistent '. It was my favourite.

Comment: @pintu-paul Connection string is in code, not config: I have an #if DEBUG directive only to go to my localhost for Debug and my remote server for Release. return @"DATABASE=mydb;SERVER=myserver;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd;Connection Timeout=60;" I only have a local instance on my dev machine (no instance on my other machine) and a remote server for my prod. The .EXE running there is the Release build.

Comment: @Solarflare This is wrapped in a try/catch that does log4net log.Error and then emails me. No exception is being caught. Regarding using a different server, definitely not. There are other processes that run on the machine using the same connection string in code (one method to set it) that work, and as mentioned in my previous comment, there isn't another MySQL instance available to this machine. Thanks for the ideas, though. This has been frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the host I use updated their version of MySQL and I didn't keep up. Since this did not generate an exception, I didn't notice it right away either. Ultimately this behavior may have been an issue of version conflict and/or currency.

It's working correctly now. What I did:

- I updated my project's target framework to .NET 4.5.2
- I ensured that MySQL.Data.dll version 8.0.13.0 was being packaged.
- I deployed and tested.

Everything worked as expected, from correcting the consistently inconsistent query mentioned above and confirming everything else that was already working fine.